# How do I install and launch the Home.app in the Apple xcode device simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, homekit, ios-homekit

When I start the XCode device simulator for any given device type (using iOS 12.1), I see many of the default Apps shipped with the iOS. However, I am missing the Home.app for controlling the Apple Home Kit services.

Searching through the web I find plenty of tutorials how to set up Apple Home Kit or how to install individual apps, but I did not find any hint how to get the original Apple Home.app running inside the device simulator.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, Home App relies on Bluetooth, BLE and other technologies that are not emulated in the iOS emulator.

Comment: Bluetooth/BLE has nothing to do with it. The app runs on the Simulator internally, but it is not shipped to customers. If that is a feature you want please do file an enhancement request at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: This is internal information from Apple ? you confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode simulator does not support Bluetooth, its means we need to use physical ios device for run and test BLE app.